# search columns in ajax_datatable_rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end  
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
end
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
end
```

And my query in datatable class songs_datatable.rb is

```
class SongDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  def get_raw_records
    Song.joins(:artist, :album).select("songs.id, songs.artist_id, songs.album_id, songs.name as song_name, songs.location as song_location, artists.name as artist_name, albums.name as album_name")
  end
end
```

What should be the name of searchable columns for songs.name, artists.name, songs.location, albums.name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def searchable_columns
  @searchable_columns ||= [
    'songs.name',
    'artists.name',
    'songs.location',
    'albums.name'
  ]
end
```

Note: One can use only database columns as sort or search fields, so the aliases like `artist_name` will not work.